# How to configure stock Ubuntu Wayland gestures (18.10)

Tags: touchpad, 18.10, wayland, gestures

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10 on my HP ZBook Studio G3. When running the default DE on Wayland (by clicking the Ubuntu Wayland option on the login screen), I get the following touchpad gestrures by default:

-two finger scrolling

-four finger swiping between desktops

-three finger pinching to open 'Activities'

However, only the two finger scrolling gesture can be configured in the touchpad settings. Does anyone know where/how to configure the other two gestures?

Answer (score 2):

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1253/extended-gestures/

Works on Pop Os Wayland...tried other things (not fusuma) but the problem was xdtools was not supported in wayland

The extension worked perfectly though.

Comment: Hi Hitesh, thank you for the answer, the version of ubuntu in the original question is end-of-life, and you have not specified which version you're using.

Comment: This just might be it. Will look in the source code to see if this interfaces with the stock Wayland gestures. It baffles me how gnome/ubuntu developers can implement a feature and leave it unconfigurable or undocumented otherwise. Very sloppy.

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 21.04 like a charm. I was looking for 3-finger left/right gestures for go back/forward in particulr. Does anyone know if it is possible to configure 3-finger up/down for maximize/hide current window as well as I couldn't find those in the provided options? Other plugins have the option to run key combinations

Answer (score 0):

Wayland doesn't support `xdotool` . which means you can't map gestures to keyboard shortcuts. But you can map it into `wmctrl` via a external script.

1. Install https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
2. Create  `~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf` with content

```
swipe_threshold 20
gesture swipe down 3 ~/.config/scripts/wsdown
gesture swipe up 3 ~/.config/scripts/wsup
```

3. Create `~/.config/scripts/wsdown` with content

```
#! /bin/bash

WS=$(wmctrl -d | grep '*' | awk '{print $1}'); wmctrl -s $(($WS - 1))
```

4. Create `~/.config/scripts/wsup` with content

```
#! /bin/bash

WS=$(wmctrl -d | grep '*' | awk '{print $1}'); wmctrl -s $(($WS + 1))
```

5. Make them excecutable

```
chmod +x ~/.config/scripts/wsdown
chmod +x ~/.config/scripts/wsup
```

6. Restart libinput-gestures

```
libinput-gestures-setup restart
```

**You can also automate this by cloning the repo https://github.com/HasinduLanka/FreshLinux and running `config.gestures.sh` script** . It will download and install libinput-gestures, configure 3 finger gestures for you.

Make sure to restart the computer after installing libinput-gestures.

Answer (score -3):

I guess a simple article like the following would be able to solve your query to the highest extent

https://italolelis.com/posts/multitouch-gestures-ubuntu-fusuma/

With the mentioned above article you would be able to install `fusuma` and make changes to the `config.yml` that you have to manually create under `/.config`. You can add your favored gesture along with which keys it would bind.

If you need any more help please ask for it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would edit my answer right away.

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering specifically about the stock gestures. There seems to be no way of turning them off, so how would that work in combination with fusuma?

Comment: @Tintin `xdotool` doesnt work on wayland, which is needed for fusuma and other gesture apps.